# CSS margin problems in ember.js

Tags: html, css, ember.js, margin

I have a weird CSS margin error with my ember.js application. I designed the homepage a long time ago but now I want to incorporate some ember into it, so I downloaded the starter kit and changed code where appropriate. Everything is working fine apart from the random margin at the bottom of the page. I looked at it in chrome and it doesn't seem to be inside the body, so it's not a CSS error that I made (hopefully). I also looked through the default ember styles (normalize.css) but there doesn't seem to be anything there. Can anyone help me out?

Links:

- [Github Code](https://github.com/yebudar/oblivion)
- [gh-pages](http://yebudar.github.io/oblivion/)

If you want any more information just ask. Thanks.

Comment: It appears to scale at a fixed aspect ratio. Try searching ember's documentation for something about scale or aspect ratio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember is a JavaScript library. It doesn't have anything to do with CSS. The issue you are having is with normalize.css.  http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Normalize sets the background on the `<html>` tag to `background:#fff`. It looks like you are setting the background color on the `<body>` tag to `background-color:#000`. All you need to do is add a rule for the `<html>` background color in your style.css to `html {background:#000}`.

Comment: aah, I see. Thank you - I would like to make this clear, though, all the folders you see and most of the files (bar index.html and buttonScript.js) are part of the ember starter kit - that means that the normalize.css is made by the ember creators, not me. But anyway, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to create a wrapper element in your application template/.hbs file, and position that element as absolute, no margins, full height and width.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @OneWay It does, even if it's not very specific. If you don't like it, downvote, don't flag.